# In an array I have to re-arrange elements such that each element starts with the same character with which the previous element ends

Tags: c++, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

Input Array: 67 96

The array can be re-arranged as:  96 67

Output: 1

Input Array2: 12 34

Elements can't be re-arranged so,
Output: 0

I'm new to Data structures and Algo, I'm not able to solve this problem. Please help me out.
Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Please, read: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/580083),
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/580083), and 
[Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166). Also, you need to choose a single programming language only.

Comment: When you encounter a problem like this, start with the simplest problem: are two numbers "compatible"? Next, simply try all possible combinations.

Comment: you need to show some effort before we can help you. Note that the title doesnt match your task. You don't have to actually rearrange the array to determine whether it can be rearranged

Answer (score 1):

Algorithms classes are *hard*. It is OK. These problems require you to really think, hard, and it sometimes takes a while to get a handle on the solution.

Some hints:

- You are *not* dealing with *numbers* to solve this problem!
  (The hint is the use of the word ‘character’.)
- You should have specific algorithms as part of your curriculum that will
  directly relate to solving this problem, such as a *topological sort*.

The first things you try may not work. Keep looking until you can solve the problem in your own head and on paper. Then invest into writing up code to do it.